# How can I interact with accented letters inside list<dynamic>?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I was assigned to upgrade a web application that was created a long time ago. In that project, data in the database was access and modify and return with a dynamic list. The relationship of some items between tables was not related by Id but rather by their title. It returns me with a list of items in which column title was assigned by item title that unfortunately contain accented letters.

**Exammple item return**

[image]

I can't access these kinds of data since accented letters are either forbidden by coding rule or there's a way but I don't know how to use it, yet. I have tried the following code, surrounding those letters with [] but it doesn't work.

```
var maBuonList = list.Select(x => x.["Ẩm_Bã bùn"]).ToList();
```

I have also tried query without dot but it returns me with another error.

```
var maBuonList = list.Select(x => x["Ẩm_Bã bùn"]).ToList();
```

The error:

```
'Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject''
```

**Error without dot**

[image: Error without dot]

Comment: How about `x["Ẩm_Bã bùn"]`?

Comment: Indexer usage would be `x["Ẩm_Bã bùn"]`, not `x.["Ẩm_Bã bùn"]` (no `.` after `x`).

Comment: I also tried that. Let me update my question with returned error.

Comment: cast it to a string, the dynamic things need explicit types when you extract them ```list.Select(x => (string)x["Ẩm_Bã bùn"]).ToList();```

Comment: It return me with the same error.

Comment: You need to explicitly cast `x` to an `IDictionary<string, object>` before you can use `["..."]`. I have linked your question to a duplicate which describes how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting list from db,you can use `Column`,and get `List<SampleModel>` rather than `List<dynamic>`:

```
public class SampleModel {
        public string Gio { get; set; }
        [Column("Ẩm_Bã bùn")]
        public double Ẩm_Bã_bùn { get; set; }


    }
```